# Confused about USB-C transfer speeds of latest MacBook Pros

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt

I was reading this 
[article](http://mashable.com/2017/07/26/usb-update-usb-3-2-faster-data-transfer-speeds/#t4DAFtSCZmqP) about the next iteration to USB-C ports. It says that the new standard will double speeds from 5 Gbps to 10 Gbps.

It also says:

> ```
> if you just bought a brand new computer with USB-C port, 
> like, for example, the 2016 MacBook Pro that I'm using to write this 
> article, you're pretty much screwed.
> ```

But according to Apple’s website their USB-C ports 
support up to 40 Gbps data transfer speeds. So this is **4 x faster**
than what the above article is saying about the new USB standard.

Can someone explain this to me? I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB-C ports on your MacBook support USB 3.1 (gen 2) AND Thunderbolt 3.

USB 3.1 gives you a transfer speed of 10 Gbit/s and Thunderbolt 3 is capable of up to 40 Gbit/s.

Note however that just because a device has an USB-C connector that doesn't imply that it supports USB 3.1 gen 2 and thus 10 Gbit/s. It can also be USB 3.1 *gen **1***, which is basically USB 3.0, which is 5 Gbit/s.

Comment: And people thought a single connector would simplify everything.

Comment: It is worse, a Type-C connector can be designed into devices that might support only USB 2.0 rates (HS, FS, LS), and it still will be a Type-C connector. So there are Type-C USB 2.0-only C-C cables, all within official specifications.